# Getting stdout from console

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to make a python script that would clone(ISO image) one usb stick to another using `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

**Here's my problem:**
I want to create progress bar showing what is done.

I tried:

1. Looking at storage space at second usb stick, but this doesn't work beacause ISO image scans also unused space
2. By adding `status=progress` to `dd` command I can get progress in terminal but I can't figure how to access stdout from python. I tried `subprocess.Popen,run(stdout = PIPE)` with and without `shell = True`
   reading `process.stdout` with `.read()`, `.read(1)`, `.readline()` or `communicate()`. Nothing worked for me. (https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/01/getting-realtime-output-using-python/)

I can see progress going on in python shell but `.read()` function always get stuck.

Part of code I am concerned about:

```
comm = 'sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb'
cloning = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(comm),stdout = PIPE,text = True)
while True:
    print(cloning.stdout.read())
```

I want something that would work like:

```
while True:
    progress = cloning.stdout.read()
    update_bar(progress)
```

I'm using python 3.7 on Raspberry

Thanks for help

Comment: It would be useful if you could give some python code that gives the same or similar output as the command that you are running so we can help you without having to find USBs

Comment: You're not supposed to edit the answer into your question. That's what the answer section is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with `status=progress`, but it outputs to stderr, not stdout. If you do `stderr = PIPE` and then read from `cloning.stderr` instead of `cloning.stdout`, it will work.

Comment: Thanks just figured it myself when trying to make workaround by saving `stdout` to file but nothing showed up. Still bugs me why something that works fine is in `stderr`.

Comment: Because `dd` is often used without `of`, and in that case the data it's copying goes to stdout.