# Python script acting different when run from /.bashrc

Tags: python, subprocess

I made a code on Raspberry pi that clone one usb stick to another. It works fine when I run it from python shell. But when I tried to run it using /.bashrc when I boot up or open terminal I get error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'`. I fugured out that by ommitting text argumet I fix this error but then my code fail to read from stderr.

My code:

```
comm = 'sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress'
cloning = subprocess.Popen(comm, shell = True, stderr = PIPE, text = True)
while True:
    output = cloning.stderr.readline()
    progress_bar(output)
```

Above code works when run directly in python. When run using /.bashrc - Command get executed when `'text'` argument deleted from code. But code get stuck at `.readline()`.

Connected question:[Getting stdout from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688714/getting-stdout-from-console)

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Given you are running from .bashrc, I wonder if your environment is fully setup.  Perhaps you are running a different version of Python.  Printout the Python version and/or path and make sure you are using the same Python in both cases.

Comment: 3.7 added the `text` argument to `subprocess.Popen`. So the Python that is running your script is before that. You could check by printing `sys.version` at the top of your script.

Comment: Yes you were right, when I run it from python shell it's version 3.7 and 2 in `/.bashrc`. Everything fixed after changing `/.bashrc` command to `sudo pyhton3 /...`. Thanks for help